# Shifting an element inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

see below CODE. HOw to shift the drop-down menu inside of `nameWrap`.

How to shift this drop-menu

```
$('#InputsWrapper').append(inWrap).append($($('#fs').html()).change(function(){
            //codeHere
        }));
```

into this div

```
nameWrap.append(
            $('<button />', { class: 'scienceL', text: 'Scirnce, type: 'button', id: 'sci_'+CretCount  }),
            $('<button />', { class: 'dramaC', text: 'Drama', type: 'button', id: 'drm_'+CretCount })
        );
```

CODE:

```
 function studentRec(e) {
        num++;
        var inWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name-wrapper', id: 'inWrap_'+num }),
            nameWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name' }).appendTo(inWrap),
            floatWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'tfArea', id: 'floatWrap_'+num }),
            outWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(floatWrap),
            tlsWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(floatWrap)

        nameWrap.append(
            $('<button />', { class: 'scienceL', text: 'Scirnce, type: 'button', id: 'sci_'+num  }),
            $('<button />', { class: 'dramaC', text: 'Drama', type: 'button', id: 'drm_'+num })
        );

        outWrap.append(
            //button
        );

        tlsWrap.append(
            //button
        );

        $('#OuterWrapper').append(floatWrap);
        $('#InputsWrapper').append(inWrap).append($($('#dropdownID').html()).change(function(){
            //codeHere
        }));
```

Comment: I think you need to explain this one more clearly. An example of the desired output HTML would help answer it. Please note that `append` does not require you to convert the text to an element first. Just `append($('#fs').html())` etc should work.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Appreciate your input. I've fixed this already. thanks :)

Comment: Appreciate if you could look in to [this simple question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383227/how-to-open-a-new-page-in-the-same-window-based-on-jquery-ajax-response). Thanks.

Comment: Best delete "fixed" questions, or post the answer too (if it may be at all helpful to others). I have responded to your other question :)